# Enabling transparency on a texture in O3D

Tags: javascript, transparency, textures, o3d

I have a texture of a set of lungs and the heart that I am applying to a series of triangles.  The texture is a .png file and has a transparent background but when I apply it in O3D it shows up with a white background.  How would I get this to show up as transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Add a transparent texture hair model
In O3d within the scene that there will be light through the effect
What is the reason

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more?  Maybe make this a comment on the question instead.